# Where did all my Outlook mail go?

Tags: mail.app, email, imap, pop

I recently attempted to switch OS X Mail from using POP to using IMAP to access my Microsoft Outlook (msn.com) e-mail account. In doing so **all** mail in my Outlook account older than a week *disappeared*.

Where did this mail go and how do I recover it?

---

FWIW, I've switched back to POP (IMAP appears not really to work), but the missing messages are still gone (and they're missing from outlook.com too).

And FWIW, here's what my "Activity" looks like after creating the Outlook.com IMAP account (while nothing beyond a handful of messages has appeared in my OSX client):

[image]

Meanwhile, the number of unread messages I see on iOS for the same account (synced using an "Outlook.com" account) is ***diminishing***!

Weirdly, when (and only when) my network connection is interrupted (e.g. if my system sleeps) the number of messages in my MSN inbox jumps a bit.

Comment: check in setting there is option for how older you want to store

Answer (score 1):

First, all your emails are still in your web version of MSN.

You need to switch the MSN to IMAP type and it is called Outlook (the web version) of Outlook, not the office version.

In your Mac Mail set up following:

Choose Account Type: IMAP.

Input the following as the Incoming Mail Server: imap-mail.outlook.com.

Choose to Use Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) for incoming mail security.

Input the following as the Outgoing Mail Server: smtp-mail.outlook.com.

Choose to Use Authentication.

Choose to Use Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) for outgoing mail security.

Depending how large your mail is it might take a while to transfer. To monitor the process turn on the Activity, located under the Window Tab in Mail app.

Comment: The messages don't show up on outlook.com (the web version). Those are the exact settings I used when I set up IMAP.

Comment: What are your settings for Trash/Deleted messages?

Comment: For the original POP account, I don't recall. For the IMAP account that I attempted to set up whatever they were by default in the OS X mail client. For the restored POP account: "Move ... " is checked, "One month ...", which I think was the default. But the issue is that I hundreds of messages in my inbox that have vanished.

Comment: I do not think they vanished. They are there in your Outlook.com, but probably moved. When changing the POP to IMAP the server needs time (sometimes hours) to sort the emails. Look in the Trash or Archive folders for your emails.

Comment: Nothing in "Deleted" older than a week, and I don't see an "Archive" folder; and nothing called "Trash" at all.

Comment: What should I expect to see in "Activity", and how long can it take. I've started another attempt, but only a handful of messages have shown up.

Comment: FWIW, I've added an image of the activity I see.

Comment: I can confirm that (at least for me and my family) all MSN mail older than a month or so is lost (without warning), on the server too.

Comment: I have a original MSN account, now some 20 years old, and it still has all emails in the web version of it.

Comment: Me too (I think I got it in the first months of MSN), following the switch to IMAP, there's nothing on the server or locally older than about a month.